# NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: A)

Tags: java, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

Out of a sudden in a formerly working application, I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError (wrong name)` which has puzzled me. I am using an XML binding framework which tries to resolve bound classes at request time by calling `ClassLoader.loadClass()` with the configured class name. (Why does it behave like that is beyond me in this case.) Now I get the exception just mentioned at `java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass()`. The documentation on the method says that it will throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` if the parameter `name` is not equal to the binary name of the class specified. I am aware that in that case one expects to get an exception of the form

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: B)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:786)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:144)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    ....
```

and this is the outcome I actually see, but the weird thing is that in my case the reported `A` and `B` are exactly the same! I tried to debug the app. The line in the JDK source reads:

```
        c = defineClass1(name, b, off, len, protectionDomain, source);
```

the value of `source` is OK. I saved the byte array `b` to a class file and inspected it with a decompiler and it's OK again. Of course `Class.forName()` reports the same error throughout, but the *really funny thing* is that if I set `name = null` in debug mode I get this beast:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "A"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:786)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
```

Now I feel completely clueless on this :( I appreciate your help.

The class loader in question is `com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.WebAppContextWithReload.WebAppClassLoaderExtension` in case that matters.

Comment: Did you make any change and recompile your application ? If so what was it ?

Comment: Let me correct: I had not actually tested this part of the application, so chances are that the bug has always been there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. Just an embarrassing capitalization issue. The names `A` and `B` in `NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: B)` actually *did* differ by a capitalization.

This happens on Windows, because of its case-insensitive file system. If you look for a class named `FooBar` and the folder contains a file `Foobar.class`, the classloader opens the class file, but discovers that internally it has a different name. Hence the exception.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I am stuck on something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check the package declaration for the class A and B. Chances are they are either without a package declaration inside some package or the package declaration is not correct.